# Is there a way to optimize this mysql code in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arduino

```
SELECT tblstud.studid,
       tblsched.ip
FROM tblstud
LEFT JOIN tblstudsched ON (tblstud.studid=tblstudsched.studid)
LEFT JOIN tblsched ON (tblstudsched.schedid=tblsched.schedid)
WHERE tblstud.rfidid='".$rfid."'
  AND tblsched.ip='".$ip."'
  AND EXISTS
    (SELECT tblsched.schedid
     FROM tblsched
     INNER JOIN tblstudsched
     WHERE tblstudsched.schedid=tblsched.schedid
       AND NOW() BETWEEN tblsched.timein AND tblsched.timeout)
```

This is my code so far and it is designed to be done after Arduino microcontroller sends data to PHP. IT takes me about 8 seconds before another data is to be accepted. I haven't checked the Arduino side but I think it's fast enough when I did another different mysql query but that one is relatively shorter than the one above.

The tables are in Inno DB but I'll try MyISAM later since the latter is the best when there are more readings than adding data.

The data types are Varchar with ranges varying from 3-30 characters each.

I'm confident also with the speed of the laptop I'm using.

Comment: Since this is working code, you're probably best posting it (also) on  Database Administrators Stack Exchange **http://dba.stackexchange.com/** - We mostly deal with busted code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Greeting, what is your opinion about Mako FW ?

Comment: Put an EXPLAIN before this query,run it,edit your question with the results.Table definitions would be helpful also.About the query you can replace your first JOIN with an INNER JOIN since the WHERE condition makes it so anyway.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'll be posting it also there. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You're welcome Jeff.

Comment: @Mihai id
select_type
table
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
Extra
1
PRIMARY
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
Impossible WHERE
2
SUBQUERY
tblsched
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
3
Using where
2
SUBQUERY
tblstudsched
index
NULL
PRIMARY
16
NULL
3
Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block...

Comment: Put it in your question ,its hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT tblstud.studid, tblsched.ip
FROM tblstud LEFT JOIN
     tblstudsched
     ON (tblstud.studid = tblstudsched.studid) LEFT JOIN
     tblsched
     ON (tblstudsched.schedid = tblsched.schedid)
WHERE tblstud.rfidid = '".$rfid."' AND tblsched.ip = '".$ip."' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT tblsched.schedid
              FROM tblsched INNER JOIN
                   tblstudsched
                   ON tblstudsched.schedid = tblsched.schedid AND
                      NOW() BETWEEN tblsched.timein AND tblsched.timeout
              );
```

First, the `LEFT JOIN` in the outer query is unnecessary, because the `WHERE` conditions just turn it into an `INNER JOIN` anyway.  Second, your `EXISTS` looks suspicious.  It is just looking to see if there are any active schedules at all in the data.  So, it is going to either filter everything out or nothing out.  It is possible that you intend:

```
SELECT tblstud.studid, tblsched.ip
FROM tblstud INNER JOIN
     tblstudsched
     ON (tblstud.studid = tblstudsched.studid) INNER JOIN
     tblsched
     ON (tblstudsched.schedid = tblsched.schedid)
WHERE tblstud.rfidid = '".$rfid."' AND tblsched.ip = '".$ip."' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tblsched
              WHERE tblstudsched.schedid = tblsched.schedid AND
                    NOW() BETWEEN tblsched.timein AND tblsched.timeout
              );
```

However, I suspect that you want schedules that meet the `where` conditions.  If so, this may be the logic that you want:

```
SELECT tblstud.studid, tblsched.ip
FROM tblstud LEFT JOIN
     tblstudsched
     ON (tblstud.studid = tblstudsched.studid) LEFT JOIN
     tblsched
     ON (tblstudsched.schedid = tblsched.schedid)
WHERE tblstud.rfidid = '".$rfid."' AND tblsched.ip = '".$ip."' AND
      NOW() BETWEEN tblsched.timein AND tblsched.timeout;
```

If this suspicious is true, then you want indexes on `tblstud(rfidid, studid)`, `tblsched(schedid, ip, timein, timeout)` and, of course, `tblstudsched(studid, schedid)`.  Note that these are *composite* indexes with multiple keys.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff Do you think that the last one is the same as the two above it? I've also thought about the last one. What I was trying to do in the exist condition is that when schedid from both tblstudsched and tblsched are equal [simply when a student is only enrolled in that subject], and the time is satisfied then it exist. Do you think It's already satisfied with the initial joins before the exists subquery? I'm not so good in logic, sorry. :)

Comment: @JeffValerio . . . Run the query on your data and see if it is returning what you expect.

Comment: all queries above return the same result. Thanks. but of course, I need the fastest one when the database goes larger. With only a few data, I can't exactly pin point whose the fastest and more optimized since my project needs faster transactions. Thanks again for the help

Comment: @JeffValerio . . . The third query is the simplest and probably the fastest on larger data sets.